# Paraview Won't Start

Tags: paraview

I've just installed Paraview on Kubuntu 16.04 largely following these instructions: http://www.paraview.org/Wiki/ParaView:Build_And_Install.

I ran `make install` and it finished successfully, but for the life of me, I can't launch Paraview. If I try to open it from the KLauncher (the 'starrt menu' of Kubuntu), nothing happens at all.

So, I tried running it from the terminal. Running `sudo find / -name "paraview"` tells me that the executable is stored at the location `/usr/local/bin/`. So, I `cd` into the directory and run `paraview`. All I get is the following:

`Aborted (core dumped)`

So, I run `sudo paraview` and I get this:

`Bus::open: Can not get ibus-daemon's address. 
IBusInputContext::createInputContext: no connection to ibus-daemon 
Aborted (core dumped)`

As suggested at this link - https://github.com/dashpay/dash/issues/20 - I run `sudo apt-get install ibus` and `ibus-daemon -d` and then run `sudo paraview` again. Now, I get this:

`Aborted (core dumped)`

Then, I find out that GUI applications must be run with `kdesudo`, not `sudo`...so, I give it a shot and I run into even more errors:

`QInotifyFileSystemWatcherEngine::addPaths: inotify_add_watch failed: No such file or directory

QFileSystemWatcher: failed to add paths: /root/.config/ibus/bus

Bus::open: Can not get ibus-daemon's address.

IBusInputContext::createInputContext: no connection to ibus-daemon`

Somehow, this time there's no `Aborted (core dumped)`, but Paraview doesn't open up anywhere either.

Edit:
I had installed paraview via apt before, but then removed it afterwards because it was crashing when trying to use certain menus. Also, I thought it would make sense to install the newest version (5.2), as the apt repo installs version 5.01.

Comment: I'd suggest just using prebuilt binaries from paraview.org

Comment: I can't find any pre-built binaries. There are binary installers and source files only.

Comment: Yes, run the binary installer, it will install the binaries. I am on LinuxMint18 64bit, no problems so far.

Answer (score 0):

As advised by Utkarsh, you can download the latest Paraview binaries at:
https://www.paraview.org/download/

Then, you can untar the downloaded archive and directly run Paraview (bin/paraview). Also, You don't need to be root to install and run it.

More generally, Paraview has a lot of dependencies and its build process may be long and difficult. Unless you have a good reason to build Paraview from scratch, it is way more easier to use the pre-built binaries.